# How do I write expressions for Birt with Mongo?

Tags: eclipse, mongodb, grails, birt

I've found the documentation page http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Fds-HowToSpecifyWhatDataToRetrieveDataFromMongoDBDataSource.html which says I can write a `Run Database Command expression` and `The default command type is FindQuery`. How do I write a FindQuery expression.

Answer (score 1):

Choose the "$query Expression" button in Edit Data Set window. Then type in the find query that you want... for example if you loaded the MongoDB sample database from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

You can do a find query such as:

```
{ pop: { $gte: 15000  } }
```

This searches for all records that have a population greater than or equal to 15000 people. You could also run some of the following find queries:

```
{ state: { $in: ["WA", "OR" ] } } //finds all of the cities in WA and OR

{$and: [{ state:"WA" },{ pop: { $gte: 50000 } }]} //finds all of the cities in WA with a population greater than 50,000-
```